# Crypto++ benchmarks cycles/byte vs. megacycles/operation

Tags: public-key, block-cipher

With respect to Crypto++ benchmarks: https://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

Why is it that there are different metrics collected for block ciphers(i.e. cycles/byte) than for public key cryptosystems(i.e. megacycle/operation)?

Why can't the RSA operations be benchmarked by using cycles/byte as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that RSA and other asymmetric operations are not used for bulk encryption (or bulk signature generation, if such a term exists).

If a lot of data needs to be signed/verified or encrypted/decrypted then a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) will be used instead.

In the case of signature generation / verification most if not all of the plaintext will be hashed by a secure hash algorithm. This hash value will be used as input for signature generation or verification using the asymmetric keys.

For encryption a symmetric cipher will be used. The symmetric key will be *wrapped* / *unwrapped* or *derived* using the asymmetric keys.

---

So you'd use just a single operation when it comes to asymmetric primitives such as RSA for most operations.

If hybrid encryption is used you'd use a single operation for the asymmetric primitive and then add the amount of time required to hash or encrypt the amount of data.

Comment: To summarize, is it plausible to say that algorithms(such as block ciphers) are characterized by cycles/bytes while single operations(such as a RSA sign on an existing hash) are characterized by  megacycles/operation?

Comment: You could say that those metrics are the most important parameters with regards to efficiency, yes. To say that they *characterize* algorithms is like saying that a car is characterized by its top speed; there are a lot of other factors to consider.

Answer (score 0):

it's not RSA can't be measured by other units, it's just does not make sense because people don't use public key system to encrypt lots of data at a time. For example, from the table you can work out how many MB/sec for RSA: if you use RSA-1024 as a block cipher (blocks of 1024 bits, or 128 bytes), it would take 0.08 ms to encrypt 128 bytes. So it would take 1000*128/0.08 $\approx$ 1.5MB/sec. (Compare to 102MB/sec of AES-GCM, you can see it's a hundred time slower)

Comment: First of all, in what sense is this answer different from my answer? Why do you think you can encrypt 128 bytes using RSA-1024? Why do you use such a low key size as example?